# How to update records based on condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `tbl_loyaltypoints` in this table a column `status = 2` has default value

Now I have following Query to get all records

```
select lp.order_id, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), FROM_UNIXTIME(lp.created_at)) as createon,
       oi.deal_id, wo.returnWithin, lp.status
from tbl_loyaltypoints lp
inner join tbl_orders ord on lp.order_id = ord.id
inner join tbl_order_item oi on lp.order_id = oi.order_id 
inner join tbl_workorders wo on oi.deal_id = wo.id 
where ord.order_type = 1
order by lp.id DESC;
```

Output:

```
order_id  createon   deal_id  returnWithin status 
1045        4           160     20          2
1044        4           160     20          2
1043        20          160     20          2
```

I want to update status `tbl_loyaltypoints.status` when `createon==returnWithin`.

Is there any way to do this using Mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform the `select` into a `join`:

```
update tbl_loyaltypoints lp inner join
       tbl_orders ord
       on lp.order_id = ord.id inner join
       tbl_order_item oi
       on lp.order_id = oi.order_id inner join
       tbl_workorders wo
       on oi.deal_id = wo.id 
    set lp.status = ??
where ord.order_type = 1 and
      DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), FROM_UNIXTIME(lp.created_at)) = wo.returnWithin;
```

You don't specify what the new status is.  The `??` is a placeholder.

Comment: The new status will be status=1